# Java class loader security handling

Tags: java, classloader

It is said that class loader of java  adds security to JRE , if its function is to load all of the classes how can it provide security to java,can you shed some light on this topic,any help is appreciated. I am talking about security from network sources,security from those classes imported from network.

Comment: You should provide further background information, e.g. any references or which kind of security you're talking about?

Comment: There is not a single class loader, but many. That permits isolation and integrity. Each instance (subclassed from `java.security.SecureClassLoader` also assign a `ProtectionDomain` to each class, using which permissions can be found.

Comment: how it is related to security from network sources?

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1997/jw-08-hood.html) might help. Java can provide a "sandbox" environment which can be customized. It restricts class from accessing resources outside the sandbox.

Comment: it is about JVM security, not JRE