# difference between keyword and literal in java

Tags: java, keyword, literals

I am new to java and was reading a book and came across these lines:

"The literals `true`,`false`and `null` are lowercase,not uppercase as in C++ language.Strictly speaking,these are not keywords but literals."

why these are literals, and what requirements are needed for some keywords to be called literal..?

Comment: Side notice : it sounds strange that your book says that `true` and `false` are uppercase in C++. They are in fact lowercase; uppercase `TRUE` and `FALSE` are macros...

Comment: @a1ex07 - The person who wrote the book was probably a Java developer, rather than a C++ developer :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keywords are words that are used as part of code structure, like `for` or `while`. They change the way a compiler handles a block of code, e.g. a `for` tells the compiler to execute the code within the specified scope repeatedly, until the given exit condition is reached. The `class` keyword tells the compiler to treat everything within the specified scope to be part of a particular class. Keyword names are restricted, so you can't use them as variable names.

Literals like `true`, `false` and `null` are values that can be assigned, but their names are restricted in the same way that keywords are, i.e. you can't have a variable called `true` or `for`. They form parts of expressions, but don't change the way a compiler handles code.

Comment: ok, so literals `true`,`false` do not instruct the compiler,like to do this or not to do..?

Comment: @sum2000 - That's one way to look at it, yes. Keywords are basically anything that the compiler considers "sacred", i.e. words that you can't use for anything but their predefined purpose. They instruct the compiler to treat something differently, e.g. perform a loop or define a class. Literals have a value instead of an action. You could think of keywords and literals as verbs and nouns respectively.

Comment: @Polynomial-thanks, can you also answer this,it would be of great help [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545096/java-class-loader-security-handling

Comment: true is a literal and a keyword, for is a keyword, "for" is a literal, 1234 is a literal....

Comment: @tkr - True. I didn't really make that very clear, so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @tkr true is not a keyword of the Java Programming Language. See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

`true`, `false` and `null` are expressions. They denote special built-in values, so they are considered *literals* (along with more traditional literals, such as `123` and `"xyz"`).

`for`, `if`, `class`, etc. are keywords. They communicate your declarations and statements to the compiler, but they do not represent values. That is why they are not *literals*.

Comment: Just for comparison: In JavaScript, we have (1) the null literal: `null`, (2) the boolean literals: `true`, and `false`, (3) numeric literals, (4) string literals, (5) regular expression literals, (6) object literals, (7) array literals, and (8) function literals (formally function expressions).

Answer (score 1):

The keywords are defined in the [Java Language Specification #3.9](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#229308). 'true' is not among them. The literals are defined in #3.10, and they include 'true'. The text of those sections answers your question completely.

Answer (score -1):

Literals are the symbols whereas the identifiers are the keywords.

Well, no, but an example may help:

12, 1e3, 0x4a, 'a', "Hello\n" -- literals 
_debug, n, stdio, main, argc, printf -- identifiers