# Is `this` a keyword or a literal?

Tags: javascript, syntax, grammar, keyword, literals

Why JS specs call `this` a keyword and not a literal?

It more seems to be a literal, because we can use it as a value, or what am I missing?

```js
return this
```

What is it then?

Comment: Because it is. Keywords are words in programming languages that have special meaning in the language. The `this` keyword is both value and a keyword. Keywords are also usually reserved, meaning you can't use them for something else. Literal has a completely different meaning.

Comment: Why would it be a literal? I guess you wanted to say "variable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter, but it's a keyword according to the specification: See [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar.html#sec-keywords-and-reserved-words) and [Literals](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar.html#sec-ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar-literals). The spec also uses the phrase "keyword `this`" in the text a fair bit, for instance (picking an instance at random), there's this text in the section on the abstract [GetThisEnvironment](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getthisenvironment) operation:

> ...It determines the binding of the keyword `this` using the LexicalEnvironment of the running execution context...

Earlier versions of the specification were [quite explicit](https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-keywords) about it:

> *[From The ECMAScript 2019 Language specification]*
>
> **11.6.2.1 Keywords**
>
> The following tokens are ECMAScript keywords and may not be used as Identifiers in ECMAScript programs.
>
> Syntax
>
> Keyword :: one of
>    `await` `break` `case` `catch` `class` `const` `continue` `debugger` `default` `delete` `do` `else` `export` `extends` `finally` `for` `function` `if` `import` `in` `instanceof` `new` `return` `super` `switch` **`this`** `throw` `try` `typeof` `var` `void` `while` `with` `yield`

*(My emphasis.)*

Continuing with your question:

> It more seems to be a literal, because we can use it as a value...

I don't think there's any conflict between something being a keyword and producing a value when used in an expression. `this` is a keyword you can use to access the value of the *ThisBinding* of the environment record for the current execution context (or the nearest one that has one).

[rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) made a really good point in the comments: They said they don't think of `this` as a literal because unlike (say) `true` and `false`, it doesn't have a fixed value. Literals always have the same value, `"a"` is always `"a"`, `true` is always `true`, `null` is always `null`, etc. But `this` has different values in different places in the code. It really acts more like a `const` than a literal; an implicit `const` set in the scope's environment object (or not, in the case of arrow function scope).

But again: It really doesn't matter. It's a reserved word that has a special purpose and function in the language, which seems sufficient that we needn't worry about whether it's a keyword or a literal (or both). :-)

Comment: Read this please https://stackoverflow.com/a/8545271/18978832

Comment: @Rect - I'll take the specification over a Stack Overflow answer, particularly one that's about a different language entirely (Java). :-) But again: It doesn't really matter.

Comment: `true`, `false` and `null` are both keywords and literals; the terms are not mutually exclusive. (That's in support of your penultimate paragraph). `this` is not a literal (to my way of thinking) because it doesn't have a fixed value, unlike `42` and  `false`. But as you say, it really doesn't matter how you and I describe a token. The semantics are precisely specified and do not depend on how the token is referred to.

Comment: @rici - Oh, I think your point about not having a fixed value is **key**; it's a CW answer, I'll add that if you don't mind. Re `true` and `false`, they're *reserved words*, but not *keywords* (as least as far as I can tell, partially by going back to the 2019 spec because the 2020 spec editor decided to remove the explicit list of keywords). But it's not important.

Comment: From your link "A keyword is a token that matches IdentifierName, but also has a syntactic use; that is, it appears literally, in a fixed width font, in some syntactic production." How do `true` etc. not conform to this definition?

Comment: @rici - I should have been more clear that in that comment that I was referring specifically to the explicit list of keywords in the 2019 spec (see the quote in the answer). In the 2020+ spec, I agree, they would seem to fit that definition. They appear in the syntax production for [boolean literals](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-boolean-literals). (Looking at my comment, **wow**, that was not clear. :-) ) It looks to me like the editor(s) decided to change their definition of keyword (or possibly clean up a previously-sloppy one).